# How do I solve $\sqrt {1/2} = \cos (a)- \sin (a)?$

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea how to do it...
I need to find $\alpha$ in this equation
$$\sqrt{1/2} = \cos(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha)$$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\cos{\alpha}-\sin{\alpha}=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{\alpha})=\sqrt{2}\cos{(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4})}$$

Comment: it`s way beyond my math skills and level

Comment: @Shay: Have you learned the summation rule $\cos{(a+b)}=\cos{a}\cos{b}-\sin{a}\sin{b}$?

Comment: I did. I just glanced at the equation and shocked, haven`t really looked at it until now, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{1/2} = \cos(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha)$$
$${1/2} = \cos^2(\alpha) + \sin^2(\alpha) - 2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)  $$
$$(1/4) = \cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)$$

Substitute for variables, and solve the system of equations, and then solve the trig equation for $\alpha$ from $\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\alpha)$ to get (Do these steps yourself; will be easier from here) :-

$$ \alpha = \pi \frac{24n-7}{12} ;  \alpha = \pi \frac{24n+1}{12}   $$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=bc455327d0772719486c1a3ecf2e96d3&title=Math%20Help%20Boards%3A%20Equation%20Solver&theme=blue